# Zabbix Database is Down

Tags: mysql, database, ubuntu, zabbix

I have got an email alert from our Zabbix server that its database is down, I have checked the logs and found the below entry. Could anyone please explain me what does it mean and why it happened?

```
1828:20160224:073113.549 [Z3005] query failed: [1317] Query execution was interrupted [select h.hostid,h.host,h.name,t.httptestid,t.name,t.variables,t.headers,t.agent,t.authentication,t.http_user,t.http_password,t.http_proxy,t.retries,t.ssl_cert_file,t.ssl_key_file,t.ssl_key_password,t.verify_peer,t.verify_host from httptest t,hosts h where t.hostid=h.hostid and t.nextcheck<=1456320673 and mod(t.httptestid,10)=5 and t.status=0 and h.proxy_hostid is null and h.status=0 and (h.maintenance_status=0 or h.maintenance_type=0)] 
1828:20160224:073113.549 [Z3005] query failed: [2006] MySQL server has gone away [select min(t.nextcheck) from httptest t,hosts h where t.hostid=h.hostid and mod(t.httptestid,10)=5 and t.status=0 and h.proxy_hostid is null and h.status=0 and (h.maintenance_status=0 or h.maintenance_type=0)]
1828:20160224:073113.549 [Z3001] connection to database 'zabbix' failed: [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
1828:20160224:073113.549 database is down: reconnecting in 10 seconds
```

And then I see these logs:

```
1843:20160224:073119.428 [Z3005] query failed: [2006] MySQL server has gone away [begin;]
1828:20160224:073123.549 database connection re-established
```

Not sure how it got connected!

Comment: Did your admin install a software update?

Comment: No, I have not installed any software update.

Comment: Check if mysqld service is running or not on the server where you have Zabbix mysql DB installed/configured. Try for ex: sudo -E service mysqld restart (using a user which has sudo access to do it) or with root.

Comment: I do not see a mysqld service, but I could see 'mysql' service is running!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your mysql server was restarted while zabbix_server was running.

If this is not the case maybe you have replication setup and the database zabbix was connected to went into a state of not being able to accept queries.

An example of this is in galera replication wsrep_ready is not `ON`